# Maclaurin series for $f(x)=\frac{1}{1+x+x^2} $

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, taylor-expansion

What is the Maclaurin expansion of  $f(x)=\dfrac{1}{1+x+x^2} $? Thank you!

Edit:

By multiplying both terms with $ (1-x) $ I got to $\dfrac{1}{1-x^3}-\dfrac{x}{1-x^3}$. Is it correct to transform this to $ \sum_{i=0}^n x^{3n} (1-x) $? I somehow have the idea that there must be only one $x$ term in a Taylor series.

Comment: The 1 corresponds to terms $1, x^3, x^6,...$ and the $-x$ corresponds to terms $-x, -x^4, -x^7,...$

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find the power series of $f(x)=\frac{1}{x^2+x+1}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1990704/find-the-power-series-of-fx-frac1x2x1)

Answer (score 3):

HINT:

$$(1+x+x^2)(1-x)=1-x^3$$

Answer (score 1):

Hint.
$$
\frac{1-x}{1-x^3}=(1-x)\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^{3n}.
$$

Comment: How does this answer differ from lab's, provided an hour ago?