# Find the power series of $f(x)=\frac{1}{x^2+x+1}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, power-series, taylor-expansion

I want to find the power series of $$f(x)=\frac{1}{x^2+x+1}$$
How can I prove the following?
$$f(x)=\frac{2}{\sqrt{3}} \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \mathrm{sin}\frac{2\pi(n+1)}{3} x^n  \,\,\,\, |x|<1$$

In particular I would like to know how to proceed in this case. The polinomial $x^2+x+1$ has no roots so here I cannot use partial fraction decomposition: what method should I use?

Comment: Expand $\frac{1}{1+X}$ and replace $X$ by $x+x^2$.

Comment: Note that $f(x) = \frac{1-x}{1-x^3}$. Can you find a power series for $g(x) = \frac{1}{1-x^3}$?

Comment: Note: You can use partial fraction decomposition with complex roots. This is sometimes interesting and/or useful as a technique, and might be of interest here. Have you computed explicitly the first few terms of the given power series? They will come out more simply than is apparent from the formula.

Answer (score 8):

$$\frac1{x^2+x+1}=\frac{1-x}{1-x^3}=(1-x)\frac{1}{1-x^3}$$ when $x\ne 1$.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I find $$\frac{1}{1-x^3}=\sum_{0}^{\infty} (-x^3)^n \,\,\,\, |x|<1$$ 
But then I don't know how to deal with $1-x$.. And in the result there is a $\mathrm{sin}$ which I have no idea where it comes from if I use this method..

Comment: Compute the first few values of $\sin(2\pi(n+1)/3)$ to see what it is.  This will also explain that $2/\sqrt{3}$ in your formula.

Comment: @Gianolepo Well, $(1-x)\frac{1}{1-x^3}$ equals $1-x$ times $\frac{1}{1-x^3}$, so you multiply them. You know how to multiply polynomials, and multiplying power series is no different.

Comment: rest is GEdgar's comment. The period is $3$. (0,1,2) (3,4,5) ...

Answer (score 4):

The polynomial $x^2+x+1=\Phi_3(x)$ has no *real* roots, but it vanishes at $x=e^{\pm\frac{2\pi i}{3}}$.
 In particular, by setting $\omega=\exp\left(\frac{2\pi i}{3}\right)$ and $\overline{\omega}=\omega^2=\exp\left(\frac{4\pi i}{3}\right)$,
$$ \frac{1}{x^2+x+1} = \frac{1}{(x-\omega)(x-\omega^2)} = \frac{i\omega^2}{\sqrt{3}}\cdot\frac{1}{1-\omega^2 x}-\frac{i\omega}{\sqrt{3}}\cdot\frac{1}{1-\omega x} $$
where the RHS, expanded as the difference between two geometric series, equals
$$ \frac{i}{\sqrt{3}}\sum_{n\geq 0}\left(\omega^{2n+2}-\omega^{n+1}\right)x^n =\frac{2}{\sqrt{3}}\sum_{n\geq 0}\sin\left(\frac{2\pi(n+1)}{3}\right)x^n$$
as wanted. That clearly simplifies, since
$$ \frac{1}{1+x+x^2}=\frac{1-x}{1-x^3} = \sum_{m\geq 0}\left(x^{3m}-x^{3m+1}\right),$$
too, and the Taylor series at the origin is unique.

Comment: Note that $\omega^2=\omega^{-1}$ which may help to see where the sine function comes from.

Answer (score 2):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[8px,border:1px groove navy]{{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$

> Lets $\ds{r \equiv -\,{1 \over 2} + {\root{3} \over 2}\,\ic = \expo{2\pi\ic/3}.\quad r\ \mbox{and}\ \bar{r}\quad \mbox{are the roots of}\quad x^{2} + x + 1 = 0}$.

\begin{align}
{1 \over x^{2} + x + 1} & =
{1 \over \pars{x - r}\pars{x - \bar{r}}} =
\pars{{1 \over x - r} - {1 \over x - \bar{r}}}{1 \over r - \bar{r}} =
\bracks{2\ic\Im\pars{1 \over x - r}}{1 \over 2\ic\Im\pars{r}}
\\[5mm] & =
-\,{2\root{3} \over 3}\,\Im\pars{\bar{r}\bracks{1 \over 1 - \bar{r}x}} =
-\,{2\root{3} \over 3}\,\Im\pars{\bar{r}\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}
\bracks{\bar{r}x}^{n}} \\[5mm] & =
-\,{2\root{3} \over 3}\,\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}
x^{n}\,\Im\pars{\bar{r}^{\, n + 1}} =
-\,{2\root{3} \over 3}\,\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}
x^{n}\,\Im\pars{\exp\pars{-\,{2\bracks{n + 1}\pi \over 3}\,\ic}}
\\[5mm] & =\ \bbox[15px,#ffe,border:2px dashed navy]{\ds{%
{2\root{3} \over 3}\,\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}
\sin\pars{2\bracks{n + 1}\pi \over 3}x^{n}}}\qquad\qquad\verts{x} < 1
\end{align}